# Can't Upload Images or Plugins via Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, ftp, folder-permissions

I have a website that I just transferred from one server to another. I did this by copying all the files via FTP from the old server to my computer and then to the new server. I changed the URL in Settings to the new url and I downloaded a copy of the database. I then uploaded the database to the new server and changed all the database info in the wp-config file. Afterwards I used Velvet Blues Update URLs to make sure all the URLs have been changed in the database.

After doing all the the website is working fine. I could update my plugins and my WordPress core files that needed updated.

**The problem is now I can't upload a plugin from my computer or any media files like images. When uploading an image, I get this message:**

“image.jpg” has failed to upload.
Unable to create directory uploads/2017/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I checked and this directory is already on the server. In FTP I changed the folder permissions to all be set to 775.

I then tried to change the folder structure for media files to not be broken into month/date folders and I get this message:

“image.jpg” has failed to upload.
Unable to create directory uploads. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I know this directory exists and is set to 775. To double check I also change the wp-content directory to the same permissions.

**What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I upload images and plugins via the WordPress backend?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually think I figured this out. I went into Settings -> Media and noticed there was a box that says Store Uploads to This Folder and had a folder for the old website. I deleted the information that was in that box and updated the settings and now it works!

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact issue today. After much troubleshooting, I solved this images not uploading issue -- specifically, when I clicked the upload button, no dialog window appeared. As a new WordPress installation, the dashboard was displaying asking if this was going to be a business or personal site. When I clicked `I DON'T NEED ANY HELP`, then I saw the normal dashboard with WooCommerce module displayed and I was able to upload media files and images from my hard drive.

I'm posting in case this answer can help someone else having this very weird problem. Also, it is possible that a plugin like OpinMonster might be what generated that "business or personal" message.